# Authorizing access to Log Viewer

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm using opcodesio/log-viewer library on my laravel application.

I'm trying to make a validation with LogViewerAuthMiddleware, where I check if my auth()->user() is logged through the barrer token, but when I type localhost/log-viewer I don't have this token.

I found a way to validate, making a button in my aplication (in react) that do a fetch to my /log-viewer passing the token, but the page is returned as a html+js response and I cannot render it, someone have an ideia that how could I do this?

(Already considered pass the token through querystring but found better not..)